# Why is singing haram?

Tags: singing

I know that according to most sources, singing is haram. Yet, I cannot see **why** it is so.

It is claimed in several sources that singing is "idle talk", that it can "mislead you from the path of Allah", that it adds "hypocrisy to the heart" .... yet, all of these arguments are not arguments, they are baseless claims and accusations.

*How* exactly is it "idle talk"? Surely there can be a lot of purpose behind ones singing.

*How* exactly does it mislead you from the path of Allah? Surely one could be singing about good things that are in accordance with the preachings of Allah and Muhammed?

*How* exactly does it add hypocrisy to the heart? This last one especially makes no sense to me.

There are many things forbidden in Islam and many of them are based on strong arguments - yet this one about singing? I don't see why it is forbidden, and, honestly, I don't think it **is** forbidden, I think this is an example of fundamentalism gone wrong.

Comment: Can you show some sources where it says singing is haram?

Comment: "I don't think it is forbidden, I think this is an example of fundamentalism gone wrong." If you want to be consistent, you have to decide which methods of deriving verdicts you accept, and then follow the results whether you like them or not. I don't know whether all schools of law forbid music - I think they all allow unaccompanied nasheed sung by men.

Comment: singing and music is different. Music is haram, not singing(until oir unless it contain something bad)

Comment: Also, most scholars consider music haram, but there are some (many) that doesn't consider all kind of music as haram. It can be read here for example: https://islamictext.wordpress.com/music-azhar-fatwa/ translated to english... (in arabic: http://dar-alifta.org.eg/AR/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=6667&LangID=1&MuftiType=)

Answer (score -1):

Allah - beginning with the name of - the most gracious, the most merciful,

Allah & his Messenger (Peace be upon him) know's the best reason behind forbidding music.

Singing is not haram, singing poets, Naat , hamd etc. is permissible.

Singing song is haram as its useless for a believer, if a men sings only for his own wife, or women sings for his husband where no other na-muharram involved and that too without any music then and only then it may be permissible. But in today's world this isn't the case.

Here are few reason's that I observe which may lead to forbidding the music.

> 1- It's creation of Satan and pushed one of the son of Adam(Alaihissalam) into the wrong path and kept away from worshiping Allah.
>
> 2- It has lot of harmful effects on nervous system and is the cause of many ailments including ulcer, diabetes and madness. It creates imbalance in human faculties, retards spiritual development, and lowers the ethical values (though few phil./dr. suggest that it has few +ve effects but here will consider the -ve).
>
> 3- It may lead people to commit adultery if it contains bad things.
>
> 4- It will instigate listener to dance, drive fastly, neglect other's,  and do whatever comes in your mind without thinking the outcome of your doing.(I have observed a lot such things).
>
> ...... list goes

Comment: "It has lot of harmful effects on nervous system and is the cause of many ailments including ulcer, diabetes and madness." I have never heard this, and I would be very surprised if this were true; it sounds on par with claims that gays or women cause earthquakes. "It will lead people to commit adultery." Mozart and Wagner are not known to be driving forces behind adultery.

Comment: first of all he asked about singing, secondly your statement about reasons why we should forbid music are baseless...

Comment: @G.Bach, hmmm if you just google you will get the side effect of music,..http://theunboundedspirit.com/the-harmful-effects-of-music-on-body-and-mind/.. and I wasn't specific about specific music..and for understanding this "It will lead people to commit adultery." you need to think like a psychologist and need to go through the ancient history where primary sources of people following wrong paths were drugs, music, & girls..

Comment: @Kilise, if he is asking about singing means its not forbidden islam, but it should be for some goodness (Poet, Praise of King or some person) not for useless things, and secondly you need to give the evidence to prove that my points are baseless..

Comment: and please don't take my words negatively as english is a language which can give 10 different meaning of a sentence..

Comment: That site does not give the impression of any kind of credibility. Clinical studies regarding music therapy on the other hand demonstrate its positive medical effects in a number of areas, see e.g. [this meta-study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4036702/). Altogether, your "reasons" for forbidding music seem like fear-mongering, not reasoned though.

Comment: i really agree with @G.Bach on this.

Answer (score -1):

For an analytical answer, consider what singing and music does. It takes your mind away from reality and makes you feel good. This is synonymous to the effect of intoxicants which is haram because anything that takes you away from reality is harmful for you, since it clouds your judgement and affects your behavior. These factors were reason enough for me to leave singing and music for good.

Comment: For the origin of music:
https://www.al-islam.org/music-and-its-effects-a-h-sheriff/origin-music

For Quranic References:
http://www.islamiq.sg/2011/04/quranic-evidence-music-haram.html
And Hadith:
http://www.islamiq.sg/2011/04/hadith-evidence-music-haram.html

Comment: You should edit and add them to your answer!

Comment: "It takes your mind away from reality and makes you feel good." I have a strong impulse to downvote this answer based on this; this seems to suggest that islam forbids any kind of amusement. Reading books does this, as does a romantic dinner with your wife, or reading a book, or playing a game.

Comment: Well you do have to understand that if you're looking through the point of view of a muslim who believes in afterlife, the world was not exactly created for pleasures, the afterworld is.

Comment: And even then there are only restrictions on most of the pleasures, the ones restricted are the severe ones, that affect a person drastically.

Comment: -1 You can't just draw conclusions on things and say "This is synonymous to the effect of intoxicants which is haram" therefore singing is haram.

If you think it is haram, don't try to explain it when you know there is no real answer for it. For instance you don't explain to people why it is haram to eat ham (pig). Also the question about singing/music isn't even clear  haram as "eating pig".

Comment: The nature of his question dictates this type of answer. He knows it's been forbidden, but he's trying to understand why. And yes I agree that this is a subjective view which is why I said that these were reasons enough for me.

Comment: Btw, singing is haram, look at Surah Luqman, Verse 6: "And of mankind is he who purchases idle talks (i.e. music, singing, etc.) to mislead (men) from the Path of Allaah without knowledge, and takes it (the Path of Allaah, the Verses of the Qur'aan) by way of mockery. For such there will be a humiliating torment (in the Hell-fire)."

Comment: Ibn Masood said about this verse "I swear by the One other than Whom there is no God that it refers to singing [ghinaa].", and he repeated this three times. Ibn Abbaas radhiyallahu'anhuma said it referred to 'singing and the like' while Jaabir radhiyallahu'anhu is reported to view its meaning to signify singing and listening to songs. Many taabi'oon such as Mujaahid, Ikrimah, Mak-hool and Umar ibn Shu'ayb viewed it as a censure of music and song. This is the majority concensus.

Comment: Even if this is rejected on the basis of not being a direct reference, the hadith contains the direct references: http://www.islamiq.sg/2011/04/hadith-evidence-music-haram.html

Comment: Now even if the words "lahwa alhadith" means "singing" in verse 31:6, we cannot draw the conclusion and say that singing itself is haram. For instance, if I would say; "It is forbidden to marry a rich women just to use her and get her money and then divorce her". This doesn't mean "It is forbidden to marry a rich women"... It is the later that is forbidden: "just to use her and get her money and then divorce her"...  Also you are providing links why MUSIC is haram and not SINGING. Its a huge different and also another topic.

Comment: The verse have also been translated in other ways for instance, 31:6: "And of the people is he who buys the amusement of speech to mislead [others] from the way of Allah without knowledge and who takes it in ridicule. Those will have a humiliating punishment."